# What is the purpose of the "Hello Dolly" plugin?

Tags: plugins, installation

Why was this plugin packaged by default? I know `Akismet` prevents SPAM but `Hello Dolly` does nothing.

Can someone please explain what the use is of the `Hello Dolly plugin?

Comment: Please keep comments to the point and on topic. There is chat for extended banter.

Answer (score 8):

> One of your old favourite songs from way back when

For the fun of it, straight from the [plugin page](https://wordpress.org/plugins/hello-dolly/).

> This is not just a plugin, it symbolizes the hope and enthusiasm of an entire generation summed up in two words sung most famously by Louis Armstrong: Hello, Dolly. When activated you will randomly see a lyric from Hello, Dolly in the upper right of your admin screen on every page.

A few interesting (and not so interesting) facts about `Hello Dolly`

- Has been downloaded more than 480 000 times, so there are people that actually uses the plugin
- Last update was in February 2012, will we ever see an update and will it survive in near future releases of Wordpress?
- The current rating of the plugin is 3.3/5, which is above average.

The truth of it, "Hello Dolly" was included in version 2.7.1 and has become a feature ever since. Whether is was a practical joke from one of the developers of Wordpress (the only way to really know is to contact the original guy who decided to include this plugin), or serves the purpose of demonstrating/showcasing the structure of a simple plugin, no one will ever really know, except that specific wordpress developer.

The sweet and short, delete it if it irritates you. No one is forcing you to use it. It really serves no purpose anyway

Answer (score 3):

It shows how simple create plugin for WordPress.

Comment: I think, you missed to hit Shift right from the beginning of your comment, right?

Comment: Again, "It shows how _simple_ ...". OO is not simple way for beginers, also Plugin API doesn't require use OOP.

Comment: @PratikJoshi Feel free do delete it. Could you please show your plugins, or maybe link to your portfolio. Just interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing, it automatically installs when you install wordpress. you can delete if you want. I recommend you to delete this plugin.

Comment: This adds nothing to the existing answers.

Answer (score 0):

I use the Hello Dolly plugin to test that there are no issues with installing, activating, and deleting a plugin when troubleshooting server or other hosting issues. It seems like a pretty safe choice to use as a test since it does not really do anything. This is probably an edge case, but I need to do this often enough that I keep a .zip of the plugin on my desktop for this reason.